# How to make relationship between a model and AbstractUser/AnonymousUser based on authentication?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) clone using Django.
In my models.py file, I have two models:

1. `CustomUser` which is inherited from `AbstractUser`
2. `Snippet` which is inherited from `Model`

```py
from .helpers import url_shortner
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Snippet(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=19, default=url_shortner, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Untitled")
    content = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now if there's a guest user want to make a snippet, as far as I know the `owner` field for this snippet should have a relation to `AnonymousUser` object so, **How to implement it?** 
Is there any kind of relations can relate `Snippet` object to these two models (CustomUser & GuestUser)? what is the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) are using unique useID for guest users so that they can identify a user (without login).

[image: see image]

When a guest user open first time their website they store a unique userID in browser local storage. after in further request they identify guest user by this userID.

In future If the user logs in then they search all content in database by userID and link with login user...

To make it...

firstly generate unique id ..

```
import uuid 

quest_id = uuid.uuid4()
```

1. Send this guest_id to browser when user come first time in your
   website.
2. get quest_id from browser in each request to identify a guest user
3. save all activity of guest user by guest_id in database
4. if guest user become login user then search all data by guest_id in
   database  and connect it with this logined user
5. To identify user is guest user or login user use ..

> ```
> if request.user.is_authenticated:
>    print('this is login user')
> ```

make owner field in your model optional
and add a extra field guest_id

```
from .helpers import url_shortner
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Snippet(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=19, default=url_shortner, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=true, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Untitled")
    content = models.TextField()
    guest_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

if user is guest user then ..

```
Snippet.objects.create(owner=None ,guest_id=guest_id .....)
```

get guest_id from browser in each request

i hope this will helpful to you !!

Comment: Oh thanks Deepak for the answer.
So for more clarification, if the user is authenticated the `owner` field will have a True value and `guest_id` is None and vice versa. Right?

Comment: if user is authenticated then Snippet.objects.create(owner=request.user,guest_id=""......)

Answer (score 0):

***You can do it with :***

**1. Change the models to :**

`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Snippet(models.Model):
     id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=19, 
     default=url_shortner, editable=False)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Untitled")
     content = models.TextField()
     creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

`

**2. To test in views.py, if the user is guest or no you can do it using:**

`if request.user.is_authenticated:
       pass`

==> This test returns false if the user is a GuestUser :)

Comment: Thanks Mahrez for the answer
I'd ask what's the deference between inherit for `AbstractUser` and make O2O relation to `User` model ?